# SLO fails when SP has timed out

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Using Spring Security SAML 1.0.10, when a SAML session has timed out on the SP, but is still active on the IdP, an SLO attempt fails.

How to reproduce

1. Set a session timeout to one minute (server.servlet.session = 1m)
2. Login on your SP
3. Login on a different secondary SP - it must use SSO
4. Wait a minute for the session to timeout
5. Make a lockout on the secondary SP

This causes a ClassCastException in Spring since `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` contains an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` which does not contain credentials. It also breaks the filter chain and a LogoutResponse is never send to the IdP and an error page is shown in the browser.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLCredential (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLCredential is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:172)
```

Is this intended, is it a bug, or have I misconfigured something?
In case of it being intended or a bug, do there exists a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in `SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout()` where the following code causes the ClassCastException. In the case a user session has timed out `auth.getCredentials()` returns an empty string.

```
SAMLCredential credential = null;
if (auth != null) {
    credential = (SAMLCredential)auth.getCredentials();
}
```

The only workaround for this I found was to create a LogoutFilter dealing with the problem.

I created a new LogoutFilter extending SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter. In the case of a LogoutRequest and a AnonymousAuthenticationToken I created a LogoutResponse. In any other case I forwarded to SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter or called a copy of a method from SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter, where I have removed the part failing.

```
  private void overwrittenLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, SAMLMessageContext context)
      throws ServletException, SAMLException, MetadataProviderException, MessageEncodingException
  {  
      var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
          logoutProfile.sendLogoutResponse(context, StatusCode.SUCCESS_URI, null);
      } else if (auth != null) {
          followNormalProcedure(request, response, auth, context);
      }
  }
```